Error when migrating gdal function proximity to aws s3
I am migrating a geoprocessing workflow to work on aws s3. I am having issues whith the function below. it first reads a geojson file, rasterize it, and then computes an euclidean distance raster. The same workflow works fine on my laptop, but when I try to read and write data on s3 the result is a raster with 0 values, the final result should be a distance to points raster. I have tested writing the rasterized geojson file to s3 and the file looks okay, but that is not the case with the gdal.ComputeProximity. The put_tif_to_s3 works fine on other worksflow so I am discarding the error is there. I am using a similar version of the approach on this threath to upload the computed result.
import geopandas as gpd
from osgeo import gdal, ogr
from S3_functions import put_tif_to_s3

def proximity_rasters(pilot_name: str, input_shp: str, mask_shp: str, out_name: str):
    """
    Process vector data into proximity raster data
    Args:
        pilot_name:
        input_shp:
        mask_shp:
        out_name:
        output:
    Returns:
        Raster proximity files
    """
    print(f"Starting to create {out_name} proximity data")
    # print(f"mask: {mask_shp}")
    # Read the GeoPandas object
    gdf = gpd.read_file(input_shp)
    mask = gpd.read_file(mask_shp)
    # Clip the func_gdf using the mask
    gdf = gpd.clip(gdf, mask)

    root = "bucket"
    dir_s3 = out_name[0].upper() + out_name[1:]
    # clipped shapefile
    clipped_shape = f"{path}/{out_name}.geojson"
    # export file
    gdf.to_file(clipped_shape)

    # set the name and location of the output raster file
    dst_filename = f"/vsimem/{out_name}.tif"

    # Open the data source and read in the extent
    pixel_size = 0.0022457882102988  # 250m

    # load the mask
    vector_ds = ogr.Open(f'{path}/{pilot_name}_mask.geojson')
    print(vector_ds)
    shp_layer = vector_ds.GetLayer()

    xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax = shp_layer.GetExtent()


    points = f'{path}/{out_name}.geojson'
    gdal.Rasterize(dst_filename, points,
                   xRes=pixel_size, yRes=pixel_size,
                   burnValues=1, outputBounds=[xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax],
                   outputType=gdal.GDT_Byte, allTouched=True)
    # ds = None
    # source_ds = None
    # print('gdal rasterize ended')

    src_ds = gdal.Open(dst_filename)

    # print(gdal.Info(src_ds))

    # get the first band of the source raster file
    srcband = src_ds.GetRasterBand(1)

    # output = f"{path}/dist_{out_name}.tif" # tested writing the rasterized file and it is fine
    output = f"/vsimem/dist_{out_name}.tif"

    # create a new raster file with the same dimensions and data type as the source raster file
    # but with only one band of Float32 data type
    empty_raster = gdal.GetDriverByName('GTiff')
    dst_ds = empty_raster.Create(output,
                                 src_ds.RasterXSize,
                                 src_ds.RasterYSize, 1,
                                 gdal.GetDataTypeByName('Float32'))
    # print(gdal.Info(dst_ds))

    # set the geotransform and projection of the output raster file
    dst_ds.SetGeoTransform(src_ds.GetGeoTransform())
    dst_ds.SetProjection(src_ds.GetProjectionRef())

    # get the first band of the output raster file
    dstband = dst_ds.GetRasterBand(1)

    # Compute the proximity of the input raster values to the raster value of 1
    # and write the resulting distances to the output raster file
    gdal.ComputeProximity(srcband, dstband, ["VALUES=1", "DISTUNITS=GEO"])

    put_tif_to_s3(output,{s3path}_output.tif, 'bucket', retries=3)

    gdal.Unlink(dst_filename)
    gdal.Unlink(output)

    print(f'{output} file processed')
    # close the input and output raster files and bands to free up memory
    srcband = None
    dstband = None
    src_ds = None
    dst_ds = None

